# print json to debug - python

Tags: python, json, debugging

I have a large input file of a JSON array and python parser json.load throws an error

> "ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 60039535 (char
>   60039534)"

How do I print the json data around the error, i.e. I want to check the (invalid) characters in the input that makes python fail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where does the JSON come from? cant you debug with a HTTP request? like fiddler?

Comment: That is on the first line char  `60039534` so read as a regular file and print the part that errors

Comment: Notepad++ -> Search -> Go to -> Line 60039534 -> Profit